# why aren't my JLabels and JTextFields showing up in the JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jlabel, jtextfield

I have a JDialog and inside it I have a JPanel that uses FlowLayout

now I've created 3 labels and text fields using the Netbeans GUI Builder, and I want to add 2 more text fields using code

I've adjusted the size of the panel so that when I add a new label and a textfield with a preferred size the new set of label - textfield will be under the previous set

somewhere in the JDialog I do something like this

```
        JLabel cores = new JLabel("Cores");
        cores.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70,15));
        first = new JTextField();
        first.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(140,20));
        JLabel power = new JLabel("Power");
        power.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70,15));
        second = new JTextField();
        second.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(140,20));
        panel2.add(cores);panel2.add(first);panel2.add(power);panel2.add(second);
```

when I compile the program, the labels don't show up and neither do the textfields

[image]

when I go down and click I have the following result

http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/13/unledlpy.png

if I type something, the text field appears

http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/6796/unledhig.png

the labels don't appear though, I don't think I made any changes to the properties, any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: We need to see the preceding code.  What layout manager is `panel2` using?  How are the top three labels/fields being added to `panel2`?  In general, you can't just arbitrarily add something to a panel and expect it to appear nicely without giving it any guidance on how it should be laid out.

Comment: Try calling `revalidate()` for panel2 after adding the new controls.

Comment: panel2 is using FlowLayout, the other three are added by Netbeans GUI builder, with the function initComponents() that is called in the constructor, also this code is in a function that is called from another class, but I have some other code that does other things and isn't related to my problem, that's why I decided to post a small part of it

Comment: Try to comment out the setPreferedSize() calls for your labels and JTextFields and create your JTextFields with new JTextField(15); call revalidate, like Bala R suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the no of columns while creating object.
like this

```
JTextField jt=new JTextField(20);
```